# Spring - Call Two Stored Procedures in a transaction but run each procedure in auto commit mode

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, stored-procedures, spring-transactions

I have two 3rd party stored procedures that I'm calling in a Spring transaction as follows:

```
    @Transactional
    public void testGetHoldings() throws SQLException {
       // calls stored procedure get_session           
       myRepo.getSession(login.getUser(), login.getPassword());

       // calls stored procedure get_data
       myRepo.getData("aDataId");       
    }
```

The transaction is required b/c the first stored procedure generates a session key. The session key can only be used by another sp call (such as get_data) in the same transaction. In addition, each statement in get_data stored procedure needs to be committed upon execution. For example,

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[get_data]
      @aDataId varchar(max)
as
begin
  -- just an example insert. actual sp has a lot of code and several inserts that
  -- must be committed immediately upon execution
   insert into tbl (col1) values ("col1")
end
```

However, `@Transactional` causes each insert to wait until the sp completes prior to be being committed.

How can I have two stored procedures be in the same transaction but allow the statements within the stored procedures to be committed upon statement execution (i.e. auto committed)? The third party sp's are in SQL Server.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do , if you want second SP to see key generated by first SP is ok , execute them in one transaction , but you can't open transaction and do commit two times, it's just impossible, what if first commit was sussessful and second commit caused error , transaction has two rollback both statements in this case.
If you want your SPs to be independent run them in two different transactions

Comment: The second SP uses and must see the key generated by the first SP. From what I can tell, the key is not committed to the DB so the second SP must be in the same transaction. However, the second SP does an insert and calls off to some other non-SQL code that will try to read the insert. The non-SQL code only reads committed data. The SQL code waits until the non-SQL code does its insert and then it continues. So, this why the second SP must commit each line as it is executed.

Comment: In this case open two separate read_commited transactions, first will insert a value and will commit result , then second transaction will be able to read this inserted row because second one has read_commited isolation level